Cannot switch to a different thread
I'm trying to create a telegram bot that can send a screenshot of a web page.
I'm using python-telegram-bot to handle telegram interactions and python-playwright to get screenshots of a page. The problem with my code is that i get the following error with Playwright:
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread

This happens because i'm declaring browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True, args=args) outside of the function that gets executed when a telegram command is called. The problem is that launching the browser every time the telegram command is called, slows my code down for about 3 seconds. How can i declare browser globally? Is it even possible?
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ParseMode
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, ChatMemberHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram.error import Unauthorized, BadRequest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

args = [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--use-gl=egl",
    ]

p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True, args=args)

def start(update, context):
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://google.com")
    page.screenshot(path="example.png")
    page.close()
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, photo=open("example.png", "rb"))  


updater = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True, workers=124)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start, run_async=True))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()


maybe you should use queue to send information to other thread, and other queue to receive result. And browser should run in loop which check if there is url in queue, create screenshot and send it back in queue - and later wait for another message in queue

adding two comments: 1) I recommend that you revoke the token that you posted for your bot "ds1testbot". 2) JayK23, your code is written for PTB v13.15 or older which is not supported by the PTB team anymore. The answer provided by Mohammed almalki basically rewrites your complete code to PTB v20.x or newer, making use of Pythons asyncio in both PTB and playwright.

Thanks! I removed the token. What i'm trying to do is try to find a way to not launch a browser instance every time the command is called since it takes some seconds. I'm trying to find a way to declare it globally without getting the "cannot switch to a different thread error"

I have worked on it, and I have changed a lot in your code,
I have made a bot to try until I finish it successfully.
I have changed the code into async code.
this is the last code:
import telegram
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Application, ContextTypes, filters
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

args = [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--use-gl=egl",
    ]


# Replace 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' with the API token you received from BotFather.
API_TOKEN = 'yours'


async def download_screan_shot(link="www.google.com", id_of_chat=None, update_to_use_it_to_send_the_file=None):
    file_name =f"{id_of_chat}_example.png"

    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(link)
        await page.screenshot(path=file_name)
        await browser.close()

    await update_to_use_it_to_send_the_file.message.reply_photo(file_name)



async def messages(update, context):
    the_gotten_message = update.message.text
    if "www" in the_gotten_message:
        await download_screan_shot(link=the_gotten_message, id_of_chat=update.message.from_user.id, update_to_use_it_to_send_the_file=update)
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


app = Application.builder().token(API_TOKEN).build()
app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT,messages))
app.run_polling()

and this is a screenshot from my bot:

I hope it works for you.
about the amount of sent links, these are failed tries.
Edit:
because you have said that you want to run the browser once, I did not find any solution for that, but I have done it using a bad idea.
it runs the browser once then saves it in public inside a list, and then uses that active browser.
this is my new code :
import telegram
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Application, ContextTypes, filters
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

args = [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--use-gl=egl",
    ]


# Replace 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' with the API token you received from BotFather.
API_TOKEN = 'yours'


opened_browser = []


async def download_screan_shot(link="www.google.com", id_of_chat=None, update_to_use_it_to_send_the_file=None):
    file_name =f"{id_of_chat}_example.png"

    # playwright = sync_playwright().start()
    # browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    # page = browser.new_page()
    # page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")
    # page.screenshot(path="example.png")
    # browser.close()


    if (not opened_browser):
        playwright = await async_playwright().start()
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch()
        opened_browser.append(browser)

    page = await opened_browser[0].new_page()
    await page.goto(link)
    await page.screenshot(path=file_name)
    await page.close()
    # await opened_browser[0].close()

    await update_to_use_it_to_send_the_file.message.reply_photo(file_name)



async def messages(update, context):
    the_gotten_message = update.message.text
    if "www" in the_gotten_message:
        await download_screan_shot(link=the_gotten_message, id_of_chat=update.message.from_user.id, update_to_use_it_to_send_the_file=update)
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


app = Application.builder().token(API_TOKEN).build()
app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT,messages))
app.run_polling()



to be honest with you, I have not seen any difference in the performance, and also I do not know what is happening there.
it is just a try, to give you an idea.
you can do the same in your code >>> I did not do that because I think you are using an old version of telegram library, and for that, I faced many errors when I tried your code with the version that I have.
tell me.

Hey, thanks a lot for your answer! The problem is that i'm looking for a way not to launch a new browser instance on every command

@JayK23 may you check the edit please.
